# Ubuntu phone - how to store data when writing HTML5 app - preferred way

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, storage, html5, xml

I started creating a simple organizing app for myself, and hit a brick fairly quickly. Wanted to have an XML list of things that would be read and updated by a HTML form.

Now I came through suggestions to use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) or try blobbing the data like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451726/saving-binary-data-as-file-using-javascript-from-a-browser). Also there's a jQuery solution to trick the browser to download the file.

The problem is that I don't want to use FileSaver.js, as I want to keep the dependencies to a minimum. Blobs look awkward, I might need to play more around them and see, but initial tests failed for me (nothing got saved).

```
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```

Downloading the file gives me no access to the history of the file, and I would simply need to recreate it every time.

So the question really becomes - is there any good way to store the data from HTML5, or is it better to switch to QML?

Comment: write a cookie. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: @j0h - hmm - sounds reasonable I totally missed that... I wonder if that would work on Ubuntu Phone. Will check out and revert, thanks for the suggestion!